# Horizontal scrollView with snapping

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm starting in Android Development, and I'm trying to do a scrollView. 
I just used a horizontalScroll view, but there is no snapping with this layout.

After some search, i found this https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager.
The operation is similar to that of the iPhone but there is some trouble to use it.

How I can do a horizontal scroll view with snapping ?

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42168070/5069561). I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't ViewPager what you're looking for?

Comment: You can use ViewPager without fragments, your PagerAdapter can return views. But if you plan to optimize for tablets, you should design with fragments.