# Horizontal Scrollview with snap effect

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I need a widget that functions as a horizontal scrollview, but snaps to the nearest value when scrolled (it should snap from value to value, and not be possible to stop the scrolling in between values). Theoretically I would solve this with a viewpager with negative margins - so that all the views are simultaneously visible, but it also "snaps". But I have a problem - if I use a viewpager then only the "foreground" (i.e. currentView) view is "clickable", and I need all onscreen visible views to be clickable at any given time. So - is there any way of having a "snapping" horizontal scroll widget where all visible views are clickable?

For example, the screen might look like this:

A B C D E

where scrolling right reveals F, G, H..

initial state should allow clicking on any of A,B,C,D,E and not just on A (if it was the "currentview")

Comment: Does [this](http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/) help? Or [this](http://androidprogrammingmadeeasy.blogspot.ro/2011/08/creating-custom-horizontal-scroll-view.html)?

Comment: @alexandru_rosianu thanks - I'm trying the first one out now

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snap ScrollView library. It supports both horizontal and vertical snap scrolling. You can add views directly. Click on this [SnapScrollView](https://github.com/santhoshkumar2794/SnapScrollView) library

And regarding click, you can implement onClick listener for each view and call correspondingly.